# How to increase the number of brokers in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka. I am trying create a topic on kafka using 3 partitions and 3 as replication factor. I am using localhost for running kafka.

When using this command,

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic activity-data --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3
```

I get an error saying -

```
RROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
```

So, how do I increase the number of brokers ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, replicas and partitions do not need to match. You can create thousands of partitions on a single broker.

Kafka runs best as a cluster, and is the only way to get more replicas is to add that many servers (brokers). Therefore, you install Kafka on other servers and make a cluster (i.e. use more machines, and not run everything on localhost)

This is explained very well in the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion).